# Separator style for header and body in FlatList

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist

Currently, I'm having a problem with FlatList.
I have a component to render a list book.
By design, the header's width is the width of the screen and the body will be padding left and right 10px.

So I used `contentContainerStyle={{paddingHorizontal: 10}}`.
But The result is that the header and body are 10px padding left and right.

Please suggest a way to resolve it. Sorry for my bad English!!

**Update:** I'm so sorry for not describing my problem thoroughly.

In `main.tsx`

```
...
public render() {
  return (
    <FlatList
      key...
      data={..}
      renderItem={this.renderItems}
      ListHeaderComponent={this.renderHeader}
      contentContainerStyle={styles.contentStyle}
    />
  );
}

private renderHeader = () => {
  return (
    <View style={style.header}
      //TODO something ...
    </View>
  );
}

private renderItems: ListRenderItem<IBook> = ({ item: {bookId} }) => bookId ?
  (
    <BookGridCell
      title={...}
      image={...}
      //TODO more..
    />
  ) : <View style={styles.emptyBox} /> 
}
```

At `renderItems`, I called a component `BookGridCell`. In this component, the design of a book is set up. So if I directly add style inside `renderItems`, each book will have a left and right margin of 10px, not the entire body.

**When use `contentContainerStyle`**
[with contenContainerStyle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lLkxI.png)

**When directly add style inside `renderItems`**
[with not use contentContainerStyle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Mu6X.png)

Comment: Remove padding from contentContainerStyle and add padding into item's design

Comment: @BrijeshShiroya I updated my question. Can you see it again?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

1. Give a style to your body.

   ```
   style={styles.bodyContainer}
   ```

and then inside StyleSheet add property.

```
    const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    bodyContainer: {
      paddingHorizontal: 10    
      },
```

This is the correct way or

2. you can directly add padding inside your View.

   ```
   style={{ paddingHorizontal: 10 }}
   ```

Comment: I updated my question. Can you see it and suggest me anyway?

Comment: This styles the list body, headers and footers. Not useful.